# Why does Phoenix need a secrets config file for environment vaiables?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm just getting started with Phoenix, and I noticed in my generated application that there's both `prod.exs` and `prod.secret.exs` files. However, the secret values loaded in the `prod.secret.exs` file comes from environment variables and aren't actually committed to the repo. If that's the case, is the `prod.secret.exs` file necessary? Could I just load everything from environment variables in `prod.exs` and call it a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prod.secret.exs` was an alternative way to manage secrets before we had easy-to-use runtime configs for releases. I believe nowadays it’s a legacy.

The reason I put this as an answer rather than a comment would be the willingness to state that there are next to zero conventions in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) world, [almost] everything is done explicitly.

`.exs` is a script file, which is not compiled by `mix` by default, unlike `.ex` files. `prod.secret.exs` might have been named `foo.bar.baz.exs` and the only reason it’s used by [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) is that it gets explicitly loaded from `prod.exs`.

The latter, in turn, gets loaded because of `config.exs` having a line `import_config("#{Mix.env()}.exs")`.

That said, with modern versions of [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) and [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) one might stick to system environment configs and [runtime release configuration](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-runtime-configuration). There is no convention enforcing developers to use `prod.secret.exs` and had never been (this file was nevertheless explicitly loaded by env-specific config.)